# Apache NiFi - Insert XML data to Postgres

Tags: xml, insert, apache-nifi

I have a simple requirement. I need to insert xml data into respective Postgres table with the use of NiFi. What would be the step by step approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [TransformXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html) processor with an [XSLT to transform your XML to JSON](https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/tree/master/conf). If your XML/JSON is "flat", meaning you have only one level of fields in your outgoing JSON, you can use [ConvertJSONToSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html) followed by [PutSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/index.html) to insert the records into your database. If your JSON is not flat and you want to transform it into a flat object (for the convert/put part), you can use [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) to do that.

In NiFi 1.2.0 you can replace the ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL part with PutDatabaseRecord; you can set up a JsonPathReader or JsonTreeReader to get the record(s) in. There isn't an XML Record Reader yet, but in 1.2.0 there is a ScriptedRecordReader and an [example Groovy script](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.2.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-scripting-bundle/nifi-scripting-processors/src/test/resources/groovy/test_record_reader_xml.groovy) for reading in a flat XML file.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable response. I would work on these lines.